# file_get_contents() - connection times out

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, php

I have debian running on vbox. I wanted to install composer like by doing:

```
$ cd /usr/src
$ sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2014/08/how-to-install-composer-on-debian/

but when I try to download the file via curl, I get:

```
Download failed: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar.sig): failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

php works fine. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I can't parse this.  Can you narrow the problem down? Do I understand correctly that it amounts to this: `curl` fails to download a file while PHP's `file_get_contents()` works OK for *the same* URL?  What I fail to get is: 1) why you say PHP works and cite an error from it at the same time? 2) why did you tag your question with `apache`? 3) why there are two different URLs used in the question?

Comment: Hi, hmm problem is solved and I don't know why. Since it's a VM, I think it was a problem with the network adapter which started wrong - now it seemed to reset and restarted somehow. So, thanks :)